# subview wantsfullscreen leaves 20px at top when rootviewcontroller is ECSlidingVIewController

Tags: iphone, ios, fullscreen, navigationcontroller

Im using an `ECSlidingViewController` as the `RootViewController`
In this i load a `UINavigationController` that eventually drills down into an image gallery.

the image gallery sets the stastusbar and navigation bar to be translucent and sets wantsfullscreen.
However this still leaves the 20px gap at the top where the status bar is.
when i tap the gallery image to hide the navbar, statusbar, and toolbar the gap remains UNTIL i rotate the phone. Then and only then does the 20px gap disappear, only now whenever i tap to unhide the navbar, statusbar, and toolbar the navbar is UNDER the statusbar until i once again rotate the phone where once again im left with a 20px gap.

Here are some examples of what im talking about

normal view when it loads (20px gap)
http://cl.ly/GSE5
fullscreen mode -> rotate -> exit fullscreen
http://cl.ly/GSMa

None of this happens when the `rootViewController` is a standard `ViewController`
What should i be looking for in the `ECSSlidingViewController` implementation that could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a view in your rootViewController with the correct size. Then you can load your image inside the view and the image size is to be the view size.

I hope this result usefull.